# TabView: Reset some dynamic variable on tab selection

Tags: dynamic, variable-definitions, gui-construction

Given a `TabView` panel like this one

```
TabView[{
  DynamicModule[{x = False}, {Checkbox[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x]}],
  "foo"}]
```

I would like to reset the value of `x` to its initial value (`False`) every time the first tab gets selected - that is, I basically want to "reset"/"reload" the tab on each selection.

Also, the variable(s) in question should remain *local* variables on a per-tab basis, if possible. This is, I hope to avoid a solution declaring `x` globally.

Any help very much appreciated (either on reloading the whole tab or on setting specific dynamic variables).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### edit

This is an old question but it came to my mind I know the solution now.

```
DynamicModule[{tab = 1},
 TabView[{
   DynamicModule[{x = False},
    Row[{  Dynamic[tab; x = False; "", TrackedSymbols :> {tab}], 
           {Checkbox[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x]}}]]
   ,
   "foo"},
  Dynamic[tab]]
 ]
```

So the trick is to keep *invisible* `Dynamic` which triggers resetting `x` whenever `tab` is changed. `x` is scoped in the tab only while `tab` is in outer `DynamicModule`.

---

#### old stuff

I don't know how to deal with it when `x` is scoped to first tab, but I don't think it is the most important thing here.

```
TabView[{
  1 -> {Checkbox[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x]},
  2 -> "foo"}, Dynamic[k, If[# == 2, x = False; k = #;, k = #] &]]
```

This solution is using `TabView` in form `TabView[{   }, i ]` which is described in `Help`.
Second argument in `Dynamic` is monitoring which tab is active and switching value of x.

Comment: But this way I'd replace the `DynamicModule` with `Dynamic`, so in each case I would need to make sure that the variable (`x`, in this case) is not used in some other instance?

Comment: unfortunately yes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version which fully localizes the variables. Other than that it does the same as Kubas answer so I'd suggest to accept his answer:

```
With[{xDefault = False},
 DynamicModule[{x = xDefault, visibleTab = 1},
  TabView[{
    Row[{Checkbox[Dynamic[x]], " ", Dynamic[x]}],
    Dynamic[x]
    }, Dynamic[visibleTab, (visibleTab = #; If[visibleTab == 1, x = xDefault]) &]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

Here is another solution which will regenerate the content completely, including initialization. It needs some hacky tricks to persuade Mathematica to really update the outermost `Dynamic` in the first tab, Mathematica seems to put quite some effort into not destroying the state of that `Checkbox`. Anyway, this seems to work for me:

```
DynamicModule[{visibleTab = 1, trigger = AbsoluteTime[]},
 TabView[{
   Dynamic[
    DynamicModule[{x = False}, 
     Row[{Pane[trigger, {0, 1}], Checkbox[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x]}]]
    ],
   "foo"
   }, Dynamic[
   visibleTab,
   (visibleTab = #; trigger = AbsoluteTime[]) &
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

You should note that in many cases it is good enough to e.g. do `Row[{trigger;Checkbox[Dynamic[x]],Dynamic[x]}]`, but here it seems that you really have to trick Mathematica into believing that the value of dummy-variable `trigger`is actually seen on screen (which it actually is, but at a size of 0x1 pixels that shouldn't be too irritating :-)). The above technique can be used to create a wrapper which makes it somewhat simpler to use:

```
reinitializingTabView[{tabs___}, opts : OptionsPattern[TabView]] := 
 DynamicModule[{tabidx, trigger},
  TabView[
   Dynamic[Row[{Pane[trigger, {0, 1}], #}]] & /@ {tabs},
   Dynamic[tabidx, (tabidx = #; trigger = AbsoluteTime[]) &],
   opts
   ]
  ]
```

and then can be used e.g. like this:

```
reinitializingTabView[{
  DynamicModule[{x = False}, {Checkbox[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x]}],
  DynamicModule[{x = False}, {Checkbox[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x]}],
  "foo"
  }]
```

handling of the second argument and options could probably be improved, but whether that's worth the effort depends on how often you'll use it...

Here is yet another solution which will localize per tab but doesn't regenerate, also quite complicated and somewhat hacky:

```
DynamicModule[{visibleTab = 1, needsupdate = False},
 TabView[{
   DynamicModule[{x = False},
    DynamicWrapper[
     Row[{Checkbox[Dynamic[x]], " ", Dynamic[x]}]
     ,
     Hold@Print["called"];
     If[TrueQ[needsupdate],
      Hold@Print["doing something"];
      x = False;
      needsupdate = False
      ],
     UpdateInterval -> Dynamic[If[TrueQ[needsupdate], 1, Infinity]],
     TrackedSymbols -> {needsupdate}
     ]
    ],
   "foo"
   }, Dynamic[visibleTab, (visibleTab = #; needsupdate = True) &]
  ]
 ]
```

If you delete the `Hold` wrapper for the `Print`s you'll note that it's now updated 3 times but it only actually does something one time.

I'd really wish this would be possible somewhat simpler but couldn't find something. I consider solutions like that to just be workarounds and hope there is something cleaner to achieve the same thing.

Comment: But it does not localize them in each tab like Bernd wants. Or maybe I've missed something.

Comment: @Kuba: that's true, but probably hard to avoid: if it would be local to the tab only, we can't access it, by definition. I see two possibilities to achieve that: either regenerate the tab content completely or create a "callback" to be accessable to the tab view selection-Dynamic. Both seem to not be simple to achieve. Maybe I'll get back when I have something working...

Comment: I Agree. So far I failed in in aproach to regenerate :)

Comment: Thanks for both proposals. If it's okay I'd wait if anyone comes up with a "regenerating" solution before I accept an answer?

Comment: @Bernd I would say You should wait :)

Comment: @Bernd: you only should accept a solution if it solves your problem. Maybe you want to reformulate the question so it becomes more clear that you really need the localization to be per tab...